# Where can i upload an Express application on webserver?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, webserver

I'm a new beginner in the express environment and i've one question(i know that it's probably a stupid question): once i've created my own app written in node.js, where can i upload this app?

Comment: As this is not really a programming question, you should probably ask this at http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks Tom, i'll ask to superuser.com!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're basically trying to figure out how to deploy a Node application so you can use it publicly.

Good question.

I think the simplest way (and this is just one of many) is to use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). I'm not affiliated with them at all.

Once you've signed up for Heroku, you can essentially deploy your Node app to their service using just a few command line commands:

```
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku open
```

This will essentially create a new Herkou app, deploy your application there, then open your browser to the newly deployed app page so you can test it out.

Heroku is a hosting provider that lets you deploy apps using Git, and handles all of the dependencies, etc.